# How to programmatically download zip files shared in google drive via form?

Tags: python-requests, google-drive-api

I have a google form that accepts file uploads, all of them in zip format.

That form generated a spreadsheet, where each row has a link with a unique uri, that represents a zip. I want to download all of these zip files to disk.

Using gspread it is easy to get all the URIs. However these do not have .zip extensions, and they seem to be google drive paths.

I've tried extracting the ids from the URI and using the requests package to get:

- `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=DRIVE_FILE_ID`
- `https://drive.google.com/u/2/uc?id=DRIVE_FILE_ID&export=download`

but neither of these approaches seemed to work.

It seems like the URI is linking to a preview of the inside of the zip, but I can't figure out how to simply download it programatically. Clicking on hundreds of links and downloading each by hand isn't really an option.

Comment: About `but neither seem to work.`, I cannot understand about your current issue. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about it, can I ask you about your current issue? 1. The files you want to retrieve are publicly shared? 2. How much maximum size of one file in the files you want to download?

Comment: I meant "neither of the approaches" worked, disambiguated on the original. 

The links exist on a spreadsheet, as they are the result of a google form where students submit some files, in zipped form. They are shared with me, but not with the general public.

Comment: The max size is 10 MB, if it matters

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `They are shared with me, but not with the general public.`, in your situation, I think that in order to download the files, it is required to use the access token. From `The links exist on a spreadsheet, as they are the result of a google form where students submit some files, in zipped form.`, when you want to retrieve the URL and file ID from the Spreadsheet and you want to download them as the files, I think that it is required to use Sheets API for retrieving the data. About `The max size is 10 MB`, when the access token is used, you can download the file.

Comment: As the official documents for achieving your goal, I thought that the following documents might be useful. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and [Ref3](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). Unfortunately, I'm not sure about your Spreadsheet. So in the current stage, I cannot propose a sample script. I apologize for this.

Comment: this seems extremely promising, thank you! I'll try and make a sample script if it works :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you have any questions in your script, feel free to tell me.

Comment: It seems to depend on `drive_service`, but it's not obvious from the documentation what that is. Is it the same thing as this? (from another example)  `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `drive_service` and `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)` in your replying, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your replying, if you are talking about https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python , `drive_service` and `service` are the same. So you can use the authorization script of Quickstart for the download sample script. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Do you also have some code that you can share in this situation? @sapo_cosmico